# Redux action req.body undefined for express route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, redux-form

I've been struggling with this feature that's supposed to send redux-form values to my express server and awaiting mongoose model.

The request body once reached the express route doesn't contain the form values that I've sent in the redux-action. The form values are properly console.logged on the client-side (inside the submitInvestment action). Though, once sent to express (using axios) -> console logging the req.body shows *undefined*

form.js

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit((values) => { this.props.submitInvestment(values) })}>

export default connect(null, actions)(reduxForm({ form: 'investmentForm' })(InvestmentForm))
```

actions.js

```
export const submitInvestment = (values) => async dispatch => {
  console.log('before request')
  console.log(values)
  const res = await axios.post('/api/investments', values);
  console.log('after request', res.data)
  // dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

route.js

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/investments', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
}
```

[on form submission (console.log browser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1skTN.png)

```
+ server logs an undefined req.body
```

Additionally; when I attempt to catch the request with the fully built route.js

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/investments', async (req, res) => {
    const { currency, units, date } = req.body;

    const investment = new Investment({ 
      currency,
      units,
      date,
      _user: req.user.id
    });

    try {
      await investment.save();
      res.status(200);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
  });
}
```

then my server logs are

```
[0] (node:25154) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.
[0] (node:25154) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Are you including `body-parser` middleware? as said in [Express req](http://expressjs.com/it/api.html#req.body)

Comment: Just for validation have you tried sending the body with `json.stringify()` and `json.parse()` it on server?

Comment: @Daniele that worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The incoming request needs to be handled by the [body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware

App.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```